# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension

Tags: selenium

```
Chrome Driver is not able to maximize the window :
ChromeDriver Version:2.24.417431
Chrome Version :57.0.2987.110
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension

    from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
      (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 10.02 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
    System info: host: 'JMP-CPE-MSDC01', ip: '169.254.133.0', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=D:\TempFiles\scoped_dir31332_1125}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.110, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: 048637a3378f2564ab12cb3eb3d2837b
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:335)
        at com.automate.SeleniumWrapper.GenUtils.getSnapShot(GenUtils.java:33)
        at com.automate.SeleniumWrapper.stepExecutor.StepDriver(stepExecutor.java:4795)
        at com.automate.testSuite.Shadow.ShadowScenario.ReEncryption443734(ShadowScenario.java:607)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
        at com.automate.Run.DTVProjectRun.main(DTVProjectRun.java:41)
 }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of Chromedriver as the version you are using does not support the version of Chrome you are using.

The latest version can be downloaded here:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads