# Chrome - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension at driver.manage().window().maximize();

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am stuck with a very unusual kind of error thrown by Chrome Browser

When I try to do maximize chrome with below line of code

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I am getting below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
(Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.05 seconds
```

By going through this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944775/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get-automation-ext) I did the below things

```
1. Updated Chrome driver to latest i.e 2.28 for my Chrome version 
   57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
2. uninstalled and re-installed Chrome
3. did a project build up in Eclipse even created a new workspace
```

but nothing helped so I used

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

it worked and Chrome driver showed no error **but** whenever I execute some piece of code like filling a form or clicking some button after that it still throws the above error after some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general the reason you see **`WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension`** can be numerous. The two most common cases to see this exception is :

1. Mismatch between **`chromedriver`** binary and **`Chrome Browser`** binary versions. **Solution** : Follow the [**`ChromeDriver Release Notes`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
2. Using `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to maximize the `Chrome Browser`. **Solution** : Use **`ChromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");`** to maximize the `Chrome Browser`.

---

As per your question the exception seems to be coming from one of the above cases.

Try out the following steps:

1. Kill all the `chromedriver` instances running in your windows Task Manager.
2. Use `CCleaner` tool to wipe out all the `OS` chores.
3. Clean all the projects in Eclipse.
4. Reboot your system once.
5. Provide the following options to start your Chrome browser:

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("start-maximized");
   options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```

Your program should work with latest chrome driver 2.28 & Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit). Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: what is the error you are getting now? may I help you out?

Comment: same error brother,form last two weeks i am facing this error earlier all scripts were running fine

Comment: Updated my Answer. Please check and let me know if it works.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks bro this time its working as per expectation can you please tell me why we are using so much of chrome option parameters and passing it to the chrome instance,i mean is there any architectural update in chrome 2.28

Comment: Where and how do I need to provide these options? Your code looks like Java.

Comment: @mcv Yes, it's Java. Which binding are you using?

Comment: My setup is all node.js. I managed to get it working by forcing version 2.30 with `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.30`. Not sure why it didn't use that version automatically. My error started after I updated OS X from Lion to Sierra.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before, remember fixing it by adding this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
//Fix for cannot get automation extension
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply m not sure about chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox"); can you please tell me what it is for ?

Comment: also i tried but in the end it still getting above error