# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension error display while using chrome driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

while executing below code using Chrome driver I have observed org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension error.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Sarika\\Web Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");         
options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

driver  = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sb_ifc0']"));
TakesScreenshot ts =((TakesScreenshot)driver);
File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/google.png"));
driver.close();
```

I am using Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get)

Comment: I referred above link and followed the steps but still I am getting the same error. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I think upgrading Selenium , chromedriver & Chrome to the latest version, you will see off the error. Else use CCleaner & take a system restart.