# driver.manage().window().maximize() issue with ChromeDriver 2.33

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The release notes for ChromeDriver 2.33 says that ""Fixes a bug which caused Resizing/Positioning Window commands to fail on Chrome 62+" however this still seems to be an issue when i am using Chrome 62+ browser. Maximizing chrome window using chrome driver results in below exception. Does anyone know a solution please?

Another thing i noticed is, though i installed latest chromedriver (v2.33) from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/, the log printed below says Driver info: **chromedriver=2.25.426923** !!

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: cannot get automation extension from unknown error:
>   page could not be found:
>   chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
>   (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.25.426923
>   (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: So what is you question exactly?

Comment: Does anyone know a solution for this? Unable to maximise browser with mentioned versions of driver and chrome.

Comment: So this is happening when you want to maximize the browser are you writing a program or is there any code base that prompt this problem?

Comment: You have multiple versions of chromedriver on your system. Get rid of the 2.25 one and it should work

Answer (score 2):

There are exactly 2 issues.

1. As you mentioned, you have installed latest chromedriver (v2.33) but the log printed below says Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923, this issue must be addressed first. You can consider to manually kill all the dangling **`chromedriver.exe`** tasks from the **`Task Manager`**. Additionally you can consider to use **`CCleaner`** to wipe out all the rotten OS stuffs from your system. Take a system reboot if required. Finally ensure that what ever the absolute location of **`chromedriver.exe`** you are using within **`System.setProperty()`** ensure that the chromedriver binary is of version 2.33.
2. Finally, it is suggested to use **`ChromeOptions`** class to **`maximize`** the Web Browser as follows:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe");
   ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
   opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
   opt.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
   driver.get("https://google.com");
   ```
3. Here are some of the alternatives which may solve your question:

   - Using `maximize()` from [WebDriver.Window](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html) interface :

     ```
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     ```
   - Using `setSize(Dimension targetSize)` from [WebDriver.Window](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html) interface:

     ```
     driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
     ```
   - Using `addArguments("--start-maximized")` through [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html):

     ```
     chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
     ```
   - Using `addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080")` through [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html):

     ```
     chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
     ```
   - Using `executeScript()` from [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) interface:

     ```
     ((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");
     ```
4. You can find a related discussion in [Chrome - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension at driver.manage().window().maximize();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get-autom/42982103#42982103).

Answer (score 0):

Use class ChromeOptions.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "h:\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there were some old chrome driver processes running in backend and same were being picked up when it was invoked via code. I deleted all processes instances, deleted old version of chrome driver, added the new 2.33 version and it worked. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason behind it may be your chrome version. Try again with updating your chrome browser. I have faced this type of issues for compatibility between chrome browser & the driver