# Window.maximize() fails on Firefox ESR v52.3.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, maximize-window

I have a regression pack created in Selenium 2.45.0 that I recently upgraded to Selenium (seleniump-java 3.4.0 and selenium server 3.7.1). Currently I have Firefox ESR v52.3.0 on my system. After upgrading to selenium 3.4.0 window.maximize() is failing with below error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to find width field
```

If i try to set the dimension by

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

it gives me following error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: setWindowRect
```

I have set path to geckodriver and also set FirefoxProfile with following options,

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\downloads");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,"
            + "application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/x-msexcel,"
            + "application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.force-enable", "false");
```

Please let me know how to maximize window on Firefox browser v52.3.0.

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [driver.manage().window().maximize() issue with ChromeDriver 2.33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802051/driver-manage-window-maximize-issue-with-chromedriver-2-33)

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium 3.x* releases the line of code to **maximize** the *Browser Window* is :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

As you mentioned of using **Firefox ESR v52.3.0** possibly *Firefox Browser* variants does gets initialized with the *Browser Window* being **maximized**. Hence there should be no additional requirement to call `driver.manage().window().maximize();` or `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));`.

*Web Browsers* which are still *OSS* compliant e.g. *Chrome* , *PhantomJS* , etc a couple of them still doesn't opens being maximized. A couple of *Chromium* issues suggested to use **`ChromeOptions`** class to **maximize** the *Web Browser* as an alternative as follows :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Here you can find a couple of discussions on the same :

- [driver.manage().window().maximize() issue with ChromeDriver 2.33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802051/driver-manage-window-maximize-issue-with-chromedriver-2-33/46803871#46803871)
- [Chrome Browser-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get/42982103#42982103)