# WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal with Chrome 70 & Chromedriver 2.43 on MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

We are on Macs, using Chrome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit), ChromeDriver 2.43.600229. Chrome windows appear, but URL is stuck at "data:,".  (stack trace below)

We found a work-around using Chrome version 69 w/ chromedriver 2.43, however, Chrome continues to insist on updating itself.

We are running Selenium-java 3.4, htmlunit-driver 2.27, testng 6.9.4, junit 4.7 with maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.1, maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.0.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 107 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'edited', ip: 'edited', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:52400}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052), userDataDir=/var/folders/cd/rrq4w8sd3gz92ygpfx5_kwtw0000gp/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.DCVcH3}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=70.0.3538.67, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: adb51408a3b04f990288d09604daa3a9
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:694)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:925)
    at ufis.common.TestSuiteUtils.getDriver(TestSuiteUtils.java:59)
    at ufis.test.cv.categories.research.independentresearch.IndependentResearchValidationTests.setUpClass(IndependentResearchValidationTests.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:140)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to **maximize** the window state of *Chrome Browser* client.

---

### Buggy Mac OSX ChromeDriver Replaced

After Chrome version 70 was released, some of you have reported that using ChromeDriver to maximize browser window on Mac no longer works. ChromeDriver Team have investigated this issue, and created a fix for it. ChromeDriver builds with the fix are now available at the following locations:

- If you are using Chrome version 70 (the current stable release), please download ChromeDriver version 70.0.3538.97 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=70.0.3538.97/
- If you are using Chrome version 71 (the current beta release), please download ChromeDriver version 71.0.3578.33 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=71.0.3578.33/

---

Snapshot of ChromeDriver Release Email

[image: ChromeDriver_new]

---

However, your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty **ancient**.

  - Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.4.0** which is almost **a year** older.

  - Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

---

From another perspective, this issue looks like a regression issue from [Feature request : ChromeDriver to support window resizing over a remote connection](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1855).

*ChromeDriver v2.43* in the [Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) have explicitly mentioned:

> ChromeDriver to support window resizing over a remote connection

However, as per *best practices* to maximize the *Chrome Browser* client it is suggested to use `ChromeOptions` class as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
opt.addArguments("--start-maximized");
opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [driver.manage().window().maximize() issue with ChromeDriver 2.33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802051/driver-manage-window-maximize-issue-with-chromedriver-2-33)

---

### Update(Nov 20, 2018)

- ChromeDriver **2.44** has been released.
- ChromeDriver **2.44** supports Chrome versions *69* to *71*
- This release is similar to ChromeDriver **2.43**, but with additional bug fixes.
- A ChromeDriver that supports **chrome 72.x** is expected to be released in the early December.

Comment: @user2093025 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Downloading the linked Chromedriver fixed my issue -- I can now run my tests on mac again.  Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Updating chromedriver to version **2.44** solved the problem for me (sort of). Don't get the error anymore, but window is maximized horizontally beyond the screen. However, the tests work.

**Option 1. Install via homebrew**

If you have previously installed it via homebrew, it has been moved to cask. So uninstall the old version:

```
brew uninstall chromedriver
```

Then install the new version from cask:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install chromedriver
```

Now you should have the new version in your path and the error is gone.

**Option 2. Download the driver**

Download the driver from

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.44/
```

And place it to your path.

Answer (score 1):

I observed this issue when running package suite and tried ChromeOptions but didnt work.So have tried this way and worked for me:

```
   Dimension ExpectedDimension=new Dimension(Screen dimensions accordingly)
   Dimension Before_Maximising= Driver.manage().window().getSize();
   Logging.info("Before_Maximising"+Before_Maximising);
   if(Before_Maximising.equals(ExpectedDimension)) {
        Logging.info("Already maximised");
   }
    else {
    Driver.manage().window().setSize(ExpectedDimension);;
    Dimension After_Maximising = Driver().manage().window().getSize();
    Logging.info("After_Maximising"+After_Maximising);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same thing happen using Selenium 3.14.0, Chrome 70, Chromedriver 2.43.

The fix for me was the remove the `--start-maximized` flag from my chromeoptions, and after the browser is open have a call to a method that does:

```
    driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

We're also running our remote automation in AWS EC2 containers running CentOS.
In Windows and Mac the above flag had no issues when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this problem using Codeception, simply change window_size option to false.

```
- Webdriver:
   url: 'http://localhost/'
   window_size: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with selenium 4.5.0 and was solved by updating to 4.9.0 (Chrome Version 112).