# WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal with ChromeDriver v2.43 and Chrome 70 on MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

My macOS just upgraded chrome automatically to v70, I upgraded chromedriver to latest version accordingly, however, my Selenium automation tests can't run due to below error when invoking

```
tempDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Error message is

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 111 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'jingfeideMacBook-Pro.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:58298}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8), userDataDir=/var/folders/mc/p32y5m3503b8qrq4nv3fjc280000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.tp2flf}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=70.0.3538.67, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5010a1722b23e3829ebcb8b45ceab234
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:783)
```

Any thoughts? I know the version of Selenium is a little bit old but i can't upgrade it due to corporate policy or something.

Balin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until issue is resolved you can bypass this with:

Custom window size

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

You can get screen resolution

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
int width = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
int height = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();
```

Argument to chrome

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
```

Javascript Executor

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("if(window.screen){
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight);
    };");
```

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to **maximize** the window state of *Chrome Browser* client.

Not sure how this issue made way with *ChromeDriver v2.43* and *Chrome Browser v70.0* combination but look like a regression issue for [Feature request : ChromeDriver to support window resizing over a remote connection](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1855).

*ChromeDriver v2.43* in the [Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) have explicitly mentioned:

> Resolved issue 1855: Feature request : ChromeDriver to support window resizing over a remote connection [[Pri-2]]

---

### Buggy Mac OSX ChromeDriver Replaced

After Chrome version 70 was released, some of you have reported that using ChromeDriver to maximize browser window on Mac no longer works. ChromeDriver Team have investigated this issue, and created a fix for it. ChromeDriver builds with the fix are now available at the following locations:

- If you are using Chrome version 70 (the current stable release), please download ChromeDriver version 70.0.3538.97 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=70.0.3538.97/
- If you are using Chrome version 71 (the current beta release), please download ChromeDriver version 71.0.3578.33 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=71.0.3578.33/

Snapshot of ChromeDriver Release Email:

[image: ChromeDriver_new]

---

However, as per *best practices* to maximize the *Chrome Browser* client it is suggested to use `ChromeOptions` class as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
opt.addArguments("--start-maximized");
opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [driver.manage().window().maximize() issue with ChromeDriver 2.33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802051/driver-manage-window-maximize-issue-with-chromedriver-2-33)

---

### Additional Consideration

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_111** which is pretty **ancient**.

  - Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.39.0** of **2013-12-16 13:18:38** which is almost **2 years** older.

  - Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: @machinarium Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue, the workaround is to comment out the code:

`tempDriver.manage().window().maximize();`

Answer (score 0):

observed this issue when running package suite and tried ChromeOptions but didnt work.So have tried this way and worked for me

```
   Dimension ExpectedDimension=new Dimension(Screen dimensions accordingly)
   Dimension Before_Maximising= Driver.manage().window().getSize();
   Logging.info("Before_Maximising"+Before_Maximising);

   if(Before_Maximising.equals(ExpectedDimension)) {
    Logging.info("Already maximised");
   }

   else {

   Driver.manage().window().setSize(ExpectedDimension);
   Dimension After_Maximising = Driver().manage().window().getSize();
   Logging.info("After_Maximising"+After_Maximising);
   }
```