# chrome driver.manage().window().maximize() exception failed to change window state to maximized

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to execute `driver.manage().window().maximize()` will throw the following exception:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to maximized, current state is normal
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)

Trying to use latest ChromeDriver (version 2.43) will not solve the problem. I noticed that many encountered this issue, but no solution is provided yet.

Comment: Did you tried ChromeOptions class like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802051/driver-manage-window-maximize-issue-with-chromedriver-2-33

Comment: Yes i did. Didn't help.