# driver.manage().window().maximize(); is not working

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am using:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

to maximize the chrome screen, but it is not working and give me a message:

> this statement is not getting executed. version of chrome is:Version
>   62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Can anybody help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Which chromedriver you are using?

Comment: chromedriver.exe

Comment: version iks like 2.33 or 2.32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-browser-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get)

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\myconfiguration\\chromedriver.exe" );
     oBrowser=new ChromeDriver();
    
     oBrowser.manage().window().maximize();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem previously, after updating chrmedriver with 2.33 Version resolve the issue, Let a try and let me know

Please download chromedriver 2.33 from this [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

Answer (score 4):

If you need the window to start maximised at launch, use the below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",prop.getProperty("driverpath"));
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

it worked for me -

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

Answer (score 2):

I replace

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

with

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

and it works for me, I am using chrome driver 2.35 on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Just look selenoid guide: http://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_custom_screen_resolution_screenresolution.
I faced this this issue and founded solution:

```
 @WhenPageOpens
public void maximiseScreen()
{
    getDriver().manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(2560,1440));
}
```

@WhenPageOpens is Serenity annotation

Answer (score -1):

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\libs\\chromedriver.exe";

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-extenstions");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code for maximize chrome browser.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();            
options.addArguments(
                Arrays.asList("--start-maximized", "allow-running-insecure-content", "ignore-certificate-errors"));
capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
```