# Selenium Python maximize Chrome browser window size to make it fit with using screen size

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How I can maximize chrome browser window size to make it fit with using screen size? I have tried doing that using the function `driver.maximize_window()`. It only maximize height but not width.

The version I'm using is: selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar and python 3.6.4

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# get initial window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.get_window_size())
# set window size
driver.set_window_size(480, 320)
print(driver.get_window_size())
# maximize window
driver.maximize_window()
print(driver.get_window_size())
driver.set_window_size(2560, 1440)
print(driver.get_window_size())
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
{'width': 1200, 'height': 1369}
{'width': 480, 'height': 320}
{'width': 1536, 'height': 1417}
{'width': 2560, 'height': 1417}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension at driver.manage().window().maximize();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get-autom)

Comment: in my case, i have multiple monitor, that I set chrome browser should open on 2560x1417. so when I use maximize_window(), it only change height to max not width.

Comment: it turns out i try another function driver.fullscreen_window\(). it seems work

Answer (score 7):

Here is what might help you with your problem if you want to start with an already maximized window:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('window-size=2560,1440')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

You can also edit the window size as you prefer. The information on this website might also come in handy: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 5):

`driver.maximize.window()` did not work for me.

This worked.

```
browser.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to maximize the browser

```
driver.maximize.window()
```