# Selenium webdriver exception is thrown for chromedriver.exe

Tags: python, selenium

When I tried to run the following command in python/Selenium from selenium

```
import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
```

the below exception is thrown:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to write automation extension zip`

Comment: Probably a permission issue

Comment: try with `browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")`. Also sometimes file dont work in root driver. Move it to a folder and then try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:cannot get automation extension for chrome with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979877/chrome-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-get-autom)

Answer (score 0):

Please put your chromedriver.exe in a folder in your desktop.

Then create a test.py in the same folder containing this minimal example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

This code was just tested on my Windows PC, works perfectly.

If you do not specify a path for chromedriver.exe Selenium will search for it in the same folder of your script.

I like this behaviour because if I need to move the script to another pc or send it to someone I just have to zip the folder and send it out.

You can clearly choose a different path for your chromedriver.exe file but you have to be sure that your user (or the user that will be running your script) 100% has permission to read and write for the specified path.

C:\ is generally not a good idea, specially in new Windows versions like 10.

The error you have pasted underlines a permission problem for the path C:\

Comment: ..IT IS NOT WORKING

Comment: Which kind of error do you get?

Did you try to download a fresh copy of chromedriver.exe?

Did you put everything in a folder on your desktop?

Comment: Also your version of chromedriver should match your version of chrome.
Please update both.

Comment: If you don't provide at least what error you get and what steps you tried it is really hard to help you

Comment: @pitto...I got the issue by checking eventdriver log.

Comment: chromedirve is blocked by antivirus software. After driver is permitted, issue is get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus blocked chromedriver.exe from running, disabling antivirus resolved my problem.